# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Tags: php

i keep getting this error on the car_detail.php page on my database

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/cars_class.php on line 228*

cars_class.php reads this on line 228

```
$this->expiry_date = date("m/d/Y", $rows['expiry_date']);
```

how can i resolve this?

Comment: `var_dump($rows['expiry_date']);` And always perform `var_dump()` on those variables you're not sure in contents of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[date()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a unix timestamp... I imagine you are passing it a date as a string.

e.g. 2010-10-10

You should use:

```
$this->expiry_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($rows['expiry_date']));
```

Or better yet, use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

```
$expiry_date = new DateTime($rows['expiry_date']);
$this->expiry_date = $expiry_date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob: I am facing the same issue but with strtotime() function. It's throwing warning on Production server while Staging and Local have no problem. PHP version difference can create some problem?

Answer (score 2):

most databases nowadays return a datestring like this "2011-03-11 20:00:00".

Easiest way (not always cheapest in terms of cpu usage) is:

```
$this->expiry_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($rows['expiry_date']));
```