# ERROR Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I get i this error on the nextgen-gallery/lib/meta.php on line 522

*`ERROR Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in`*

This line includes:

```
$date_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_time );
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5254553/1409082)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`$date_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_time) );`

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `strtotime()` function you can cast a string to a [Datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

```
$dateTime= new DateTime($date_time);
$date_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTime);
```