# How to convert timestamp to date in php using date() without warping data?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I am using the php function date() to take a timestamp and turn it into a readable date.  It is stored under type=timestamp, function=now in mysql, and the timestamp I'm using reads "2013-12-17 16:23:00" in the database.  And it can echo out perfectly using $date1.  However, when I try to convert it using this code:
`echo date('m/d/Y, $date1)`
It turns into "12/31/1969" on the page.  I have no idea why.

Comment: `date()` expects a UNIX timestamp (= the number of seconds since January 1 1970), not a string date. You'd have to use `strtotime()` to make it a timestamp first

Comment: I didn't see that comment when I posted my answer, aha sorry!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254553/warning-date-expects-parameter-2-to-be-long-string-given-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a MySQL timestamp you'll need to make use of the `strtotime` function

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date1));
```

The function `strtotime` will take must formats of date/timestamp and convert it into a unix timestamp which can then be converted to another readable format using `date()`. Reference: http://php.net/strtotime

The above works, but it's not to say that it's the best way of doing so, I'd be happy to hear alternatives.

The date you're getting is because `date()` expects a unix timestamp (seconds that have passed since 1/1/1970), and I assume that your web server is configured to a UTC-, so you're getting the day before. It's an annoying bug that can come from the way that MySQL handles timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the strtotime function in order to get the correct date format

print date( 'm/d/Y' , strtotime( $date1 ) )

Hope it helps your need