# Error: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I am getting a error on following code.
kindly someone help me to fix it.

## Model

```
function getappointmentlist($practicien , $datee) {
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('rdv');
            $this->db->join('contact', 'contact.id = rdv.contact_id');
            $this->db->where('people_id',$practicien);
            $this->db->where(date('Y-m-d' , 'day'), $datee);
            $this->db->order_by('startTime', 'ASC'); 
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query;
        }
```

i get the following error:
A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Filename: models/appointment.php

Line Number: 16

Input values :
$practicien = 18
$datee = 2013-05-13
```

PS: day is a field in table rdv. ex data in day field is: 2012-02-15 09:41:35

Comment: What is 'day' ? A column in db table?

Comment: yes, day is a column in rdv table ex data : 2012-02-15 09:41:35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 'day' is a column in mysql table, try

```
 $this->db->where('DATE(day)', $datee);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$this->db->where(date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('day')), $datee);
```

and refer to this one [Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254553/warning-date-expects-parameter-2-to-be-long-string-given-in)

Comment: day field in rdv table holds the value of date and time , ex data : 2012-02-15 09:41:35

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation [right here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you see that the date function expects a timestamp as second parameter – it simply doesn't know what to do with the String `'day'` you're passing in (`date('Y-m-d' , 'day')`). If you just want the current time, leave the second parameter out.

Comment: day field in rdv table holds the values like 2012-02-15 09:41:35

Comment: For which date are you trying to get the results? The one in `$datee`?

Comment: i have a input date at $datee. Need to get data from rdv table using that. for this, i'm considering a condition tyo check day field(datetime) in rdv table with $datee(date). got it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('DATE(day)', $datee);
```

the above code fixed my problem.
great solution by Ramesh.