# Post comments on articles with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, comments

I have a problem I want to post comments on articles, but no comments will appear.

This is articles collection:

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda"),
    "title": "Hello World !",
    "content": "My new article is beautiful",
    "saved_at": ISODate("2015-04-04T18:07:32.519Z"),
    "comments": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
    ]
}
```

We can see, I don't know why comments are null. So when I comment in the comments there is just:  says...
                          1:00 am, January 1

> comment.php  :

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['article_id'];
try
    {
    $mongodb    = new MongoClient();
    $collection = $mongodb->myblogsite->articles;
    }
catch (MongoConnectionException $e)
    {
    die('Failed to connect to MongoDB ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
$article = $collection->findOne(array(
    '_id' => new MongoId($id)
));
$comment = array(
    'name' => $_POST['commenter_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['commenter_email'],
    'comment' => $_POST['comment'],
    'posted_at' => new MongoDate()
);
$collection->update(array(
    '_id' => new MongoId($id)
), array(
    '$push' => array(
    'comments' => $comments
    )
));
header('Location: blog.php?id=' . $id);
?>
```

> blog.php:

```
        <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
try
    {
    $connection = new MongoClient();
    $database   = $connection->selectDB('myblogsite');
    $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
    }
catch (MongoConnectionException $e)
    {
    die("Failed to connect to database " . $e->getMessage());
    }
$article = $collection->findOne(array(
    '_id' => new MongoId($id)
));
?>
```

And html form as below :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;

      charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
    <title>My Blog Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contentarea">
    <div id="innercontentarea">
        <h1><?php echo $article['title']; ?></h1>
        <p>
            <?php echo $article[ 'content']; ?> </p>
        <div id="comment-section">
            <h3>Comments</h3>
            <?php if (!empty($article[ 'comments'])): ?>
            <h3>comments</h3>
            <?php foreach($article[ 'comments'] as $comment): echo $comment[ 'name']. ' says...';?>
            <p>
                <?php echo $comment[ 'comment']; ?> </p> <span>

        <?php echo date('g:i a, F j', $comment['posted_at']); ?>

      </span>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <?php endforeach; endif;?>
            <h3>Post your comment</h3>
            <form action="comment.php" method="post"> <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="commenter_name" class="comment-input" />
                <br/>
                <br/> <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="commenter_email" class="comment-input" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <textarea class="input-label" name="comment" rows="5"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $article['_id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save" /> </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What your problem you want to insert comment in comments. And what you tried ?

Comment: for example : i have blog with articles and i want add form for comment articles. So I made the form but when I finished filling out the form, there is just : says ... 1:00 am, January 1 and not the content

Comment: plese post questions in well formatted http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in inserting in `comments`  array, for this mongo [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) helps more. For this I create a following scenario If you fill forms with comment like `my first comment` then you should update documents as below , If `comments` key not presents then used mongo [upsert and multi](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)  here `true` means create `comments` key if not presnts and `false` means to avoid mulit documents update.

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda")},{"$push":{"comments":"my first comment"}},true,false)
```

And if you want to insert multiple comments at same time then use [$pushAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) so above query replace as

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda")},{"$pushAll":{"comments":["my first comment","my second comment","my third comment"]}}},true,false)
```

Or If you want to set time when individual comments created then try this

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda")}, {"$push":{"comments":{"comment":"my first comment","commentTime": new Date()}}}},true,false)
```

If push all comments with different time stamp then used

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda")},{"$pushAll":{"comments":[{"comment":"A" ,"time":new Date()},{"comment":"B","time":new Date()}]}}},true,false)
```

or all comments with same time stamp then try this

```
var currentsystemTime = new Date()
db.collectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda")},{"$pushAll":{"comments":[{"comment":"A" ,"time":currentsystemTime},{"comment":"B","time":currentsystemTime}]}}},true,false)
```

Comment: I do not understand something, when a person is going to comment on an article I need to change all the time in the terminal and add $pushAll?

Comment: @AnisMrad check my new updated answer may that will solve your problem

Comment: That is what it appears to me after  "_id" : ObjectId("5521b3350faaf22c04b7acdb"), "title" : "Troisieme article", "content" : "Voici le troisième article", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-04-05T22:12:05.582Z"), "comments" : [ null, null, "first comment", "second comment" ] } and i have a lots of error on blog.php

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/Site/blog/blog.php on line 56
m says...

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'comment' in...  Warning: Illegal string offset 'posted_at' in. the time has not changed

Comment: after update : { "_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda"), "title" : "Hello World !", "content" : "My new article", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-04-04T18:07:32.519Z"), "comments" : [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "my first comment", "my second comment", "my third comment", { "comment" : "A", "time" : ISODate("2015-04-06T11:39:37.359Z") }, { "comment" : "B", "time" : ISODate("2015-04-06T11:39:37.359Z") } ] }

Comment: I think you should remove your old documents `db.collectionName.remove("_id" : ObjectId("552028640faaf24450b7acda"))` and then check

Comment: yes you should create new article,  and check as per above output new article contains proper information without `null`

Comment: now i create new article { "_id" : ObjectId("552276250faaf2d202b7acd9"), "title" : "Article 4", "content" : "This is article 4", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-04-06T12:03:49.118Z") }

Comment: now i comment { "_id" : ObjectId("552276250faaf2d202b7acd9"), "title" : "Article 4", "content" : "This is article 4", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-04-06T12:03:49.118Z"), "comments" : [ null ] }

Comment: @AnisMrad check my new updated answer and may be problem in `$comment`  look this value maybe it contains blank array or you should debug your code because above query work well on Mongo shell, a problem in your `php` code let debug first code and definitely you should find out why that `null` value inserted

Comment: I am a beginner with php, I am lost now I do not know where to start I put all the php code at the top of the page

Comment: @AnisMrad actually I don't know more about `php` my expertise in MongoDB but you should find on internet more about `php` and check what exactly the problem. Best luck :)

Comment: one error : Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

Comment: @AnisMrad check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254553/warning-date-expects-parameter-2-to-be-long-string-given-in

Probally this error in PHP syntax error